# split row names with multiple delimiter in to separate column

Tags: r

How can i split the row names in my data frame which are separated by multiple delimiter in to separate columns.

```
df1 <-  
                                   test1                  test2
        1:740001-760000                 1                -1
        1:760001-780000                 1                -1
        1:780001-800000                 1                -1
        1:800001-820000                 1                -1
        1:840001-860000                 1                -1
        1:860001-880000                 1                -1
```

expected output

```
    Chr    Start   End                 test1            test2
    1      740001 760000                 1                -1
    1      760001 780000                 1                -1
    1      780001 800000                 1                -1
    1      800001 820000                 1                -1
    1      840000 860000                 1                -1
    1      860001 880000                 1                -1
```

Comment: Just use `strsplit` i.e. `do.call(rbind, strsplit(row.names(df1), "[:-]"))` and `cbind` with the rest of the dataset

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(as.data.table(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), "rn", ":|-", fixed = FALSE)`.